# How to send email to multiple recipients in codeigniter using smtp?

Tags: codeigniter-3

Hi friends i am creating send email using SMTP server in codeigniter.In this code, I am trying to send email to customer, e_commerce, account and branch. It's sending to customer only.

```
                    $order_number = $data['order_number'];
                    $order['order'] = $this->Checkout_model->get_order_details($order_number);
                    $branch_id = $this->Checkout_model->getbranch_id($data['order_number']);
                    $branch_email = $this->Checkout_model->getbranch_email($branch_id);
                    $mesg = $this->load->view('mail/email_order', $order, true);
                    $customer_email = $response['customer_email'];
                    $ecommerce_email = 'codeqtechnology06@gmail.com';
                    $account_email ='arpitsingh791@outlook.com';




                    $list = array($customer_email, $ecommerce_email, $account_email, $branch_email);


                    $mail_count= count($list);
                    for($i=0;$i<$mail_count;$i++)
                    {
                    $this->load->library('email');
                    $config=array(
                        'protocol' => 'smtp',
                        'charset'=>'utf-8',
                        'wordwrap'=> TRUE,
                        'mailtype' => 'html',
                        'smtp_host' => 'mail.xxxxx.com',
                        'smtp_user' =>'sales@xxxx.com',
                        'smtp_pass' =>'sales',
                        'smtp_port' =>xy,
                        'smtp_timeout' => 30,
                    );    
                    $mail_id = $list[$i];

                    $this->email->initialize($config);

                    $this->email->from('sales@xxxx.com', 'ABC Order');
                    $this->email->to($mail_id);
                    $this->email->bcc('arpitsingh791@gmail.com');
                    $this->email->subject('Order : '.$order_number);
                    $this->email->message($mesg);
                    $this->email->send();
                    $this->email->clear();

                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a loop and if you did you shouldn't load and initialize the email class inside the loop.

I assume that all the set up you show (and the set up you don't show) is producing the correct values for all the variables. (If not, all bets are off.)

This solution uses the fact that you can provide the `Email::bcc()` method an array of addresses. By doing that you can send emails to all the interested parties in one go.

You would be better off using */application/config/email.php* to provide the configuration. Below I used your config array, but I pass it to the email constructor. That way a call to `$this->email->initialize($config);` is not needed.

```
$order_number    = $data['order_number'];
$order['order']  = $this->Checkout_model->get_order_details($order_number);
$branch_id       = $this->Checkout_model->getbranch_id($data['order_number']);
$branch_email    = $this->Checkout_model->getbranch_email($branch_id);
$mesg            = $this->load->view('mail/email_order', $order, true);
$customer_email  = $response['customer_email'];
$ecommerce_email = 'codeqtechnology06@gmail.com';
$account_email   = 'arpitsingh791@outlook.com';

$bcc_list = array('arpitsingh791@gmail.com', $ecommerce_email, $account_email, $branch_email);

$config  = array(
    'protocol'     => 'smtp',
    'charset'      => 'utf-8',
    'wordwrap'     => TRUE,
    'mailtype'     => 'html',
    'smtp_host'    => 'mail.xxxxx.com',
    'smtp_user'    => 'sales@xxxx.com',
    'smtp_pass'    => 'sales',
    'smtp_port'    => xy,
    'smtp_timeout' => 30,
);
$this->load->library('email', $config);


$this->email
    ->from('sales@xxxx.com', 'ABC Order')
    ->to($customer_email)
    ->bcc($bcc_list)
    ->subject('Order : '.$order_number)
    ->message($mesg)
    ->send();
```

Comment: thank you so much, I have fixed my self. and your code is also working.